# Is it possible to use Where and Having together in the same query if you want one or the other and they don't relate?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that depends on a where statement and also depends on a having statement, but they're not connected.  I'm trying to figure out how to write a query/subquery that uses them both at once.  Here's the code to make a dummy table.

```
    CREATE TABLE #Hospital (
    [hospitalname] varchar(255),
    [Year] int,
    [Date] date,
    [Outcome] varchar(255),
    [Percentile] int,
    [Length of Stay] int
    ); 

    INSERT INTO #Hospital ([hospitalname],[Year],[Date],[Outcome],[Percentile],
    [Length of Stay])
    VALUES ('MayoClinic', '2020', '01-01-2020', 'A','1','150'),
    ('ClevelandClinic', '2020', '01-02-2020', 'A','1','152'),
    ('MayoClinic', '2020', '01-01-2020', 'B','1','130'),
    ('ClevelandClinic', '2020', '01-01-2020', 'A','1','130'),
    ('ClevelandClinic', '2020', '01-01-2020', 'A','2','135'),
    ('ClevelandClinic', '2020', '01-01-2020', 'A','3','150'),
    ('ClevelandClinic', '2020', '01-01-2020', 'A','4','165'),
    ('ClevelandClinic', '2020', '01-01-2020', 'A','1','132'),
    ('ClevelandClinic', '2020', '01-01-2020', 'A','2','137'),
    ('ClevelandClinic', '2020', '01-01-2020', 'A','3','154'),
    ('ClevelandClinic', '2020', '01-01-2020', 'A','4','165')
    ;
```

From this data, I'm trying to take the results only if it meets one of two criteria:
-The maximum Length of Stay for that day, hospital and group if the percentile equals 2
OR 
-The Length of Stay for any group where there is ONLY one data point in the group

My results should look like this for data points where the percentile is equal to 2:

```
      hospitalname      Year    Date        Outcome   Median_LOS
      ClevelandClinic   2020    2020-01-01  A         137
```

My results should look like this for cases where there is only 1 object in the group:

```
     hospitalname        Year   Date        Outcome  Median_LOS
     ClevelandClinic     2020   2020-01-02  A        152
     MayoClinic          2020   2020-01-01  A        150
     MayoClinic          2020   2020-01-01  B        130
```

The following code gets me the results for the first half.

```
   select 
   [hospitalname],
   [Year],
   [Date],
   [Outcome],
   max([length of stay]) as 'Median_LOS' 
   from #hospital
   where percentile = 2
   group by [hospitalname],[Year],[Date],[Outcome]
```

This code gets me the results for the second half.  I'm struggling to figure out how to combine the where and the having together in a subquery that calculates both at once, without choosing one over the other.  Please advise if possible.

```
   select 
   [hospitalname],
   [Year],
   [Date],
   [Outcome],
   max([length of stay]) as 'Median_LOS' 
   from #hospital
   where percentile = 2
   group by [hospitalname],[Year],[Date],[Outcome]
   having (select count(percentile)) = 1 
   order by [hospitalname],[Outcome],[Year],[Date]
```

Comment: Have you tried `UNION ALL`?

Comment: It's possible to write this is a single query (with single table scan), but odds are you'll end up making it a CTE (or just use conventional subqueries). The UNION approach works well and would be much more legible, though you'll get two table scans. IF not for performance, why not go with the simpler code?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way, use an UNION, or you could stored the results in a Temp table and the do the select on that table. If the UNION doesnt solve your problem please comment to see what you really want.

```
select [hospitalname],[Year],[Date],[Outcome],max([length of stay]) as 'Median_LOS' 
from #hospital where percentile = 2 group by [hospitalname],[Year],[Date],[Outcome]
UNION
select 
[hospitalname],[Year],[Date],[Outcome],max([length of stay]) as 'Median_LOS' 
from #hospital group by [hospitalname],[Year],[Date],[Outcome]
having (select count(percentile)) = 1 order by [hospitalname],[Outcome],[Year],[Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    select 
            [hospitalname],
            [Year],
            [Date],
            [Outcome],
            max([length of stay]) as 'Median_LOS' 
   from     #hospital
   group by [hospitalname],[Year],[Date],[Outcome], 
            CASE percentile WHEN 2 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
   having   count(percentile) = 1 
        OR  CASE percentile WHEN 2 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END = 2
   order by [hospitalname],[Outcome],[Year],[Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   [hospitalname],
   [Year],
   [Date],
   [Outcome],
   max([length of stay]) as 'Median_LOS' 
from
(
select 
   [hospitalname],
   [Year],
   [Date],
   [Outcome],
   [length of stay],
   percentile,
   count(percentile) over(partition by [hospitalname],[Outcome],[Year],[Date]) as percentilecount
   from #hospital
) as src
where (percentile = 2 or percentilecount = 1)
group by [hospitalname],[Year],[Date],[Outcome]
```